# Pass current UIComponent as "this" in action MethodExpression

Tags: jsf, primefaces, uicomponents

Is there a possibility to pass current UIComponent as `this` in action's MethodExpression?

XHTML

```
<p:menuitem id="test" value="Test" action="#{controller.test(this)}" update="test" />
```

Java

```
public String test(MenuItem item) {
    // Do something with item
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the implicit EL variable `#{component}` for this:

```
<p:menuitem ... action="#{controller.test(component)}" />
```

with

```
public void test(UIComponent component) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Or if you're only interested in for example the `id` attribute:

```
<p:menuitem ... action="#{controller.test(component.id)}" />
```

with

```
public void test(String id) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Or if you're only interested in for example the `value` attribute:

```
<p:menuitem ... action="#{controller.test(component.value)}" />
```

with

```
public void test(String value) {
    // ...
}
```

---

You can alternatively also use [`UIComponent#getCurrentComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) for this:

```
<p:menuitem ... action="#{controller.test}" />
```

with

```
public void test() {
    UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    String id = component.getId();
    String value = ((MenuItem) component).getValue();
    // ...
}
```